# Are mutual funds allowed to trade intraday in india?

Tags: india, mutual-funds, day-trading

Are mutual funds allowed to trade intra-day in india?

Comment: do you mean can the fund manager trade intra-day or can the fund be traded intra-day?

Answer (score 3):

A fund manager can do intra day trading. There is no restriction.